# Why do I get System.InvalidOperationException back from a WSDL call but not from the same call to another service?

Tags: wcf

I have created service to get the country details information of various clients, but while hosting the service I am getting this exception. I am using basic http binding.

```
An ExceptionDetail, likely created by IncludeExceptionDetailInFaults=true, whose value is:
System.InvalidOperationException: An exception was thrown in a call to a 
WSDL export extension:   
  System.ServiceModel.Description.DataContractSerializerOperationBehavior
  contract: http://tempuri.org/:IReferenceDataService ----> 
     System.Runtime.Serialization.InvalidDataContractException: 
     Type 'Pariwaar.BusinessObject.CountryBO' cannot be serialized. 
     Consider marking it with the DataContractAttribute attribute, 
     and marking all of its members you want serialized with the 
     DataMemberAttribute attribute. See the Microsoft .NET Framework 
     documentation for other supported types.
   at System.Runtime.Serialization.DataContract.DataContractCriticalHelper.ThrowInvalidDataContractException(String message, Type type)
   at System.Runtime.Serialization.DataContract.DataContractCriticalHelper.CreateDataContract(Int32 id, RuntimeTypeHandle typeHandle, Type type)
   at System.Runtime.Serialization.DataContract.DataContractCriticalHelper.GetDataContractSkipValidation(Int32 id, RuntimeTypeHandle typeHandle, Type type)
   at System.Runtime.Serialization.DataContract.GetDataContract(RuntimeTypeHandle typeHandle, Type type, SerializationMode mode)
   at System.Runtime.Serialization.DataContractSet.GetDataContract(Type clrType)
   at System.Runtime.Serialization.DataContractSet.GetItemTypeDataContract(CollectionDataContract collectionContract)
   at System.Runtime.Serialization.DataContractSet.AddCollectionDataContract(CollectionDataContract collectionDataContract)
   at System.Runtime.Serialization.DataContractSet.Add(XmlQualifiedName name, DataContract dataContract)
   at System.Runtime.Serialization.DataContractSet.Add(Type type)
   at System.Runtime.Serialization.XsdDataContractExporter.Export(Type type)
   at System.ServiceModel.Description.MessageContractExporter.ExportType(Type type, String partName, String operationName, XmlSchemaType& xsdType)
   at System.ServiceModel.Description.DataContractSerializerMessageContractExporter.ExportBody(Int32 messageIndex, Object state)
   at System.ServiceModel.Description.MessageContractExporter.ExportMessage(Int32 messageIndex, Object state)
   at System.ServiceModel.Description.MessageContractExporter.ExportMessageContract()
   at System.ServiceModel.Description.DataContractSerializerOperationBehavior.System.ServiceModel.Description.IWsdlExportExtension.ExportContract(WsdlExporter exporter, WsdlContractConversionContext contractContext)
   at System.ServiceModel.Description.WsdlExporter.CallExtension(WsdlContractConversionContext contractContext, IWsdlExportExtension extension)
   --- End of inner ExceptionDetail stack trace ---
   at System.ServiceModel.Description.WsdlExporter.CallExtension(WsdlContractConversionContext contractContext, IWsdlExportExtension extension)
   at System.ServiceModel.Description.WsdlExporter.CallExportContract(WsdlContractConversionContext contractContext)
   at System.ServiceModel.Description.WsdlExporter.ExportContract(ContractDescription contract)
   at System.ServiceModel.Description.WsdlExporter.ExportEndpoint(ServiceEndpoint endpoint, XmlQualifiedName wsdlServiceQName)
   at System.ServiceModel.Description.WsdlExporter.ExportEndpoints(IEnumerable`1 endpoints, XmlQualifiedName wsdlServiceQName)
   at System.ServiceModel.Description.ServiceMetadataBehavior.MetadataExtensionInitializer.GenerateMetadata()
   at System.ServiceModel.Description.ServiceMetadataExtension.EnsureInitialized()
   at System.ServiceModel.Description.ServiceMetadataExtension.HttpGetImpl.InitializationData.InitializeFrom(ServiceMetadataExtension extension)
   at System.ServiceModel.Description.ServiceMetadataExtension.HttpGetImpl.GetInitData()
   at System.ServiceModel.Description.ServiceMetadataExtension.HttpGetImpl.TryHandleDocumentationRequest(Message httpGetRequest, String[] queries, Message& replyMessage)
   at System.ServiceModel.Description.ServiceMetadataExtension.HttpGetImpl.ProcessHttpRequest(Message httpGetRequest)
   at System.ServiceModel.Description.ServiceMetadataExtension.HttpGetImpl.Get(Message message)
   at SyncInvokeGet(Object , Object[] , Object[] )
   at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.SyncMethodInvoker.Invoke(Object instance, Object[] inputs, Object[]& outputs)
   at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.DispatchOperationRuntime.InvokeBegin(MessageRpc& rpc)
   at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ImmutableDispatchRuntime.ProcessMessage5(MessageRpc& rpc)
   at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ImmutableDispatchRuntime.ProcessMessage4(MessageRpc& rpc)
   at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ImmutableDispatchRuntime.ProcessMessage3(MessageRpc& rpc)
   at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ImmutableDispatchRuntime.ProcessMessage2(MessageRpc& rpc)
   at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ImmutableDispatchRuntime.ProcessMessage1(MessageRpc& rpc)
   at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.MessageRpc.Process(Boolean isOperationContextSet)
```

I have `businessobject[datamember]` in another project. I have referred its dll here.

You can view my class

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Runtime.Serialization;
using System.ServiceModel;
using System.Text;
using Pariwaar.BusinessObject;
using Pariwaar.DataAccessLayer;

namespace Pariwaar.WCFServices.SVC
{
    // NOTE: If you change the class name "ReferenceDataService" here, you must also update the reference to "ReferenceDataService" in Web.config.
    public class ReferenceDataService : IReferenceDataService
    {
        ReferenceData objDAL = new ReferenceData();

        public List<CountryBO> GetCountry()
        { return objDAL.GetCountry(); }

        public List<StateBO> GetState(int CountryId)
        { return objDAL.GetState(CountryId); }

        public List<CityBO> GetCity(int StateId)
        { return objDAL.GetCity(StateId); }
    }
}
```

Why is this working fine with another WCF service, but giving me an error with another service?

Comment: yes, but is your "CountryBO" class marked with [DataContract] and [DataMember] ?? Can you show us the **CountryBO** class??

Comment: Hi, did you found a solution for this problem?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Well, the error is pretty clear:

> System.Runtime.Serialization.InvalidDataContractException:
>   Type
>   'Pariwaar.BusinessObject.CountryBO'
>   **cannot be serialized**. Consider marking
>   it with the **DataContractAttribute**
>   attribute, and marking all of its
>   members you want serialized with the
>   DataMemberAttribute attribute.  See
>   the Microsoft .NET Framework
>   documentation for other supported
>   types.

You're obviously using a datatype `Pariwaar.BusinessObject.CountryBO` as parameter or return value for one of your WCF service methods, but that class doesn't have a `[DataContract]` attribute on it.

See the MSDN docs on [Using Data Contracts](http://Pariwaar.BusinessObject.CountryBO) to learn about data contracts and how to make your objects useable by WCF. See this [blog post - WCF Basics: Data Contracts](http://www.arquitecturadesoftware.org/blogs/hugobatista/archive/2005/11/06/wcf-basics-data-contracts.aspx) for another view on the same topic.

All complex types (e.g. class) should be marked with [DataContract], all fields that you want to include in your WCF messages with [DataMember]:

```
[DataContract]
class Pariwaar.BusinessObject.CountryBO
{
   [DataMember]
   string CountryName { get; set; }

   [DataMember]
   string CountryCurrency { get; set; }

   [DataMember]
   string CountryISOCode { get; set; }

   ........
}
```

Marc

Comment: please see my edited content... i posted my class also here.. as well as some description

Comment: -1 The solution will work but the reasoning is incorrect: Against popular belief it is optional to decorate your classes with [DataContract] and [DataMember]. By default, DCS infers the data contract based on public read/write properties and fields. However, if one of those is not serializable - then you get the error of the OP. Alternative solution would be to decorate [IgnoreDataMemberAttribute] on those fields. See MSDN: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733127.aspx

Comment: @tsemer: it is *optional* since **.NET 3.5 SP1** - it was **mandatory** before that. And even if it's not mandatory anymore - I believe it's **good practice** to always explicitly decorate your WCF data classes with `[DataContract]` and `[DataMember]`. Also gives you an option to specify a data contract XML namespace and other options ...

Comment: @marc_s .NET 3.5 SP1 came out in 2008 and your post is from 2009, so it should have been taken into account. Good practice is debatable separately, but regardless your solution gives an incorrect reasoning for the OP's exception. Not having [DataContract] is not the reason. Having a non-serializable field is the reason, and it can be solved in multiple ways.

Answer (score 4):

Hi I encountered the same problem, It was because there was no default constructor on the object CountryBO.

Comment: I had the same problem and your answer was the solution for me.

Answer (score 0):

This error may occur in case of by mistake we have used a type which is not kept contract and might have been used in a List<> or public variable of another DataContract

HydTechie