# An exception was thrown in a call to a WSDL export extension - WCF

Tags: c#, web-services, wcf, wsdl

I am trying to connect a webservice with a windows form application, when i try to open the link to the webservice from the browser i get this error message:

```
An ExceptionDetail, likely created by IncludeExceptionDetailInFaults=true, whose value is:
System.InvalidOperationException: An exception was thrown in a call to a WSDL export extension: System.ServiceModel.Description.DataContractSerializerOperationBehavior
 contract: http://tempuri.org/:IMobileWS ----> System.InvalidOperationException: For request in operation UploadFile to be a stream the operation must have a single parameter whose type is Stream.
   at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.StreamFormatter.ValidateAndGetStreamPart(MessageDescription messageDescription, Boolean isRequest, String operationName)
   at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.StreamFormatter.Create(MessageDescription messageDescription, String operationName, Boolean isRequest)
   at System.ServiceModel.Description.MessageContractExporter.ExportMessage(Int32 messageIndex, Object state)
   at System.ServiceModel.Description.MessageContractExporter.ExportMessageContract()
   at System.ServiceModel.Description.WsdlExporter.CallExtension(WsdlContractConversionContext contractContext, IWsdlExportExtension extension)
   --- End of inner ExceptionDetail stack trace ---
   at System.ServiceModel.Description.ServiceMetadataBehavior.MetadataExtensionInitializer.GenerateMetadata()
   at System.ServiceModel.Description.ServiceMetadataExtension.EnsureInitialized()
   at System.ServiceModel.Description.ServiceMetadataExtension.HttpGetImpl.InitializationData.InitializeFrom(ServiceMetadataExtension extension)
   at System.ServiceModel.Description.ServiceMetadataExtension.HttpGetImpl.GetInitData()
   at System.ServiceModel.Description.ServiceMetadataExtension.HttpGetImpl.TryHandleDocumentationRequest(Message httpGetRequest, String[] queries, Message& replyMessage)
   at System.ServiceModel.Description.ServiceMetadataExtension.HttpGetImpl.ProcessHttpRequest(Message httpGetRequest)
   at SyncInvokeGet(Object , Object[] , Object[] )
   at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.SyncMethodInvoker.Invoke(Object instance, Object[] inputs, Object[]& outputs)
   at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.DispatchOperationRuntime.InvokeBegin(MessageRpc& rpc)
   at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ImmutableDispatchRuntime.ProcessMessage5(MessageRpc& rpc)
   at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ImmutableDispatchRuntime.ProcessMessage11(MessageRpc& rpc)
   at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.MessageRpc.Process(Boolean isOperationContextSet)
```

In the third line i noticed that it is in the UploadingFile function:

> System.InvalidOperationException: For request in operation UploadFile
>   to be a stream the operation must have a single parameter whose type
>   is Stream

this is the UploadFile function:

```
// In the interface
[OperationContract]
    [WebInvoke(Method = "POST", UriTemplate = "/UploadFile/{senderId}/{fileName}"
      , ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json)]
    string UploadFile(string senderId, string fileName ,Stream image);

// Implementation
public string UploadFile(string senderId, string fileName, Stream image)
    {
// ..... unwrapping the stream and saving the file
}
```

This function usually works for uploading images without any problems. 
So why this message is appearing?

Note: I tried the ansowers in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1914452/system-invalidoperationexception-an-exception-was-thrown-in-a-call-to-a-wsdl-ex), It did not work

This is my Web Config file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <configSections>

    <section name="entityFramework" type="System.Data.Entity.Internal.ConfigFile.EntityFrameworkSection, EntityFramework, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false" />

  </configSections>

  <appSettings>
    <add key="aspnet:UseTaskFriendlySynchronizationContext" value="true" />
  </appSettings>

  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5" />
    <httpRuntime />
    <pages controlRenderingCompatibilityVersion="4.0" />
  </system.web>

  <system.serviceModel>
    <services>
      <service name="MyPortal.MobileWS" behaviorConfiguration="ServiceBehavior">
        <endpoint binding="webHttpBinding" contract="MyPortal.IMobileWS" behaviorConfiguration="webHttp" />
      </service>
    </services>

    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior name="ServiceBehavior">
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" httpsGetEnabled="true"/>
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true" />
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>

      <endpointBehaviors>
        <behavior name="webHttp">
          <webHttp />
        </behavior>
      </endpointBehaviors>

    </behaviors>

    <standardEndpoints>
      <webHttpEndpoint>
        <standardEndpoint name="" helpEnabled="true" automaticFormatSelectionEnabled="false" defaultOutgoingResponseFormat="Json" maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647"
                           maxBufferSize="2147483647"
                              maxBufferPoolSize="4194304"
                          transferMode="Buffered"  />
      </webHttpEndpoint>
    </standardEndpoints>

    <serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true" multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />

    <bindings>
      <webHttpBinding>
        <binding
          maxBufferPoolSize="2147483647"
          maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647"
          maxBufferSize="2147483647" transferMode="Streamed">
        </binding>
      </webHttpBinding>
    </bindings>

  </system.serviceModel>

  <system.webServer>
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true" />
    <directoryBrowse enabled="true" />
  </system.webServer>

  <connectionStrings>
  ....
  </connectionStrings>
  <entityFramework>
    <defaultConnectionFactory type="System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.SqlConnectionFactory, EntityFramework" />
    <providers>
      <provider invariantName="System.Data.SqlClient" type="System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices, EntityFramework.SqlServer" />
    </providers>
  </entityFramework>
</configuration>
```

Comment: Can you publsih your WCF configuration ?

Comment: I've added the web config file @RomEh

Comment: Have you tried ta add a mexHttpBinding endpoint ?

Comment: no, i tried to add baseHttpBiding endpoint @RomEh

Comment: actually i have no experience with WCF, but the error shows that UploadFile function should not take more than 1 parameters, and i need the other parameters, so what mexHttpBinding can affect this ?

Comment: You will be able to see your wsdl. As you have a "particular" behavior on your endpoint, you may need to add this binding.

Comment: I got another errors `Could not find a base address that matches scheme https for the endpoint with binding MetadataExchangeHttpsBinding. Registered base address schemes are [http]` there is no tools to help us modify Web.config file ? should it really be hard coded by hand?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/93073/discussion-between-rom-eh-and-mbh).